# Как прижать абсолютный элементы к нижей границе row?

Tags: вёрстка, позиционирование

Можно ли прижать круги к нижней границе row / фона ? Не изменяя **.bootom-blank-icon { position: absolute}** и без добавления к **bg-head { position:relative}**

```css
.bg-head {
  background-image: url(https://k60.kn3.net/taringa/C/5/D/B/1/3/VCLR/A17.jpg);
  height: 900px;
}

.bootom-blank-icon {
  bottom: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 34pt;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
}

.icon-circle {
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px #fff solid;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row bg-head">
    <div class="bootom-blank-icon">
      <a class="icon-circle" href="/"></a>
      <a class="icon-circle" href="/"></a>
      <a class="icon-circle" href="/"></a>
      <a class="icon-circle" href="/"></a>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[codeopen](https://codepen.io/Sinecuraweb/pen/eVYLMR)**

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

или так:

```
.row {
        display: grid;
        align-items: end;
    }
```

или на костылях (89px=height+padding+border):

```
.bootom-blank-icon::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
}


 .bootom-blank-icon {
        margin-top: -89px;
    }
```

Comment: c бустраповским row не работают первые 2 примера, а третий способ не подойдет, т.к высоту я не знаю  у бекграунда ( верстка резиновая)

Comment: https://codepen.io/Sinecuraweb/pen/eVYLMR  вот тут бутстрап подключен

Comment: селектору .bg-head задать можете?

Comment: неа. если получиться сбросьте рабочий пример с правками